# Does each chunking of a batch goes through the same process of Queued, Processing and Completed states?

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits, asynchronous

As per documentation :

> The maximum number of asynchronous Apex method executions (batch Apex, future methods, Queueable Apex, and scheduled Apex) per a 24-hour period 
> For Batch Apex, method executions include executions of the start, execute, and finish methods.

Does this mean each chunking of a batch goes and occupies the `AsyncApexJob` and contributes to `DailyAsyncApexExecutions`?

For eg: `Start` method from batch queries `50,00,000` and if we make the batch size as `100` , then the total `sub-batches` processed would be `50,000`. Would `50,000` be added to the `AsyncApexJob` where other async processes are running? And would it also contribute (+50,000) to `DailyAsyncApexExecutions` ?

Comment: Every call to `start`, `execute` and `finish` uses one async call, so if there are 5 chunks the whole batch execution costs 7 async calls.

Comment: @PhilW So in a heavy load scenario, where there are hundreds of Queueable job running every minute, the Batch `execute` method also may get delayed? As when the every execute goes into `AsyncApexJob` it will only run when system resources are available. Right?

Comment: Absolutely. More than that, you can only have 5 batches executing concurrently with another 100 sat in the flex queue awaiting execution. And on top of that only one batch `start` method is ever running at any one time (which can make it a handy synchronisation point). As to just how many queueables you can execute, while their concurrency is effectively unlimited (like futures) there is still that daily maximum for all async processing (queueables, futures and batchable start/execute/finish).

Comment: @PhilW We are facing this scenario where in heavy load only 1-2 queueable jobs are in processing status, rest all are in `Queued` status.
We have almost 60K queueable jobs in queued status. We reached out to SF but no concrete answer from their end.

Comment: I expect this is throttling in action, perhaps because you exceeded your daily limits (or some other reason).

Comment: @PhilW Reason is still unknown, because we are definitely within our limits as our limits are pretty high. From OrgLimits class we can see `Limit Name  -------> DailyAsyncApexExecutions                                                                                        Total Limit -------> 1111000                                                                                       Limit Value -------> 109919`

Comment: You probably do need Salesforce to explain what is throttling your org's async processing.